# EF 4.1 ExecuteStoreQuery with joins

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to map ExecuteStoreQuery with joins result to domain objects?

i.e. we have 2 domain objects

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and now if i'll run this query:

```
 string query = "select * from Order as Order 
    inner join Customer as Customer on Order.CustomerId = Customer.Id 
    where freetext(Order.Description, 'something')";
_objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Order>(query);
```

the result will be collection of orders with all customers set to null.
how can i fix this ?

Thank You!